# MySQL syntax error in subquery

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with this MySQL query?

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT did FROM publications where group IN 
(SELECT s_group FROM subscriptions where uid1='$id')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I am getting syntax error:

```
        You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's_group FROM 
subscriptions where uid1='34846')' at line 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP` is a reserved keyword. Surrounding with ` will signify it's a column name:

```
SELECT did FROM publications where `group` IN 
(SELECT s_group FROM subscriptions where uid1=1)
```

Comment: Best practice I think is to always use them.

Comment: But the parser did not balk at `group`... it had an issue at `s_group` ?  Suggests the OP has either not posted his exact query, or his exact error message.  Beware.

Answer (score 1):

you have to write "group" column like `group`, because keyword group is reserved keyword in MySQL.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT did FROM publications where `group` IN 
(SELECT s_group FROM subscriptions where uid1='$id')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Or you can user alias

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT did FROM publications p where p.group IN 
(SELECT s_group FROM subscriptions where uid1='$id')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

follow what @paulius said and then check data type of uid1 if it's number than remove quotes from $id

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I can't comment on an author's post that is why I answered here and now I can comment here.